# is there any msmq opensource lib

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, msmq

as you know .when the client send messages to the server I must write a multiple process program to process the messages.I am not good at multiple process code it's easy to wrong.
so please tell me !

Comment: What do you think this mythical library would add for you? You're still going to have to write code specific to your problem domain. That code will still have to be thread safe, if you *are* going to have the server process multiple messages in parallel (which is by no means a requirement of all solutions)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look at  WCF Instance Management  for maybe an easier way to set up MSMQ handling

Relevant Examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx